# Retrieving info from database only show me one field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a problem retrieving information from the database.
I have a function

```
public List<string> Selectquery(string sql)
{
   return GetContext().ExecuteQuery<string>(sql).ToList();
}
```

where the variable sql:

```
var sql = "SELECT  s.UserName AS username, st.Name AS status_name, c.FirstName FROM client c JOIN Suser s ON (c.UserID=s.ID) JOIN Status AS st ON (c.StatusID=st.ID) GROUP BY s.UserName,st.Name";
```

In the other file I call the function it is like this:

```
List<string> SUsers = _DAO.Selectquery(sql);
```

When I see the result with a breakpoint, and make a foreach for example:

```
foreach (string su in SUsers)
{
   String str = su;
}
```

I only see the username, and the others fields disappear. I have change List for `IEnumerable` and the result is the same.
So I don't know whats is happening.
I would Appreciate your help.
Thank You.

Comment: I think it has something to do with trying to fit a dataset result inside of <string>. string implies that it will only return one string, which is probabaly why you get the single username

Comment: take a look here http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/ASPNetBinding.html || http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/low-level-ado-api/executing-stored-procedures/data-access-tasks-adonet-stored-procedures-multiple-result-set

Answer (score 2):

Create a class like this:

```
public class clients{
private string username;
public string Username
{
   get
   {
      return username;
   }
   set
   {
      username = value;
   }
}
private string status_name;
public string Status_name
{
   get
   {
      return status_name;
   }
   set
   {
      status_name = value;
   }
}
private string firstName; 
public string FirstName 
{
   get
   {
      return firstName ;
   }
   set
   {
      firstName  = value;
   }
}
}
```

> and use `List<clients>` for your method to map the result.

**Edit:** if your query is dynamic you can use the `dynamic` specifications of C#:

create a dynamic entity like this:

```
public class DynamicClass : DynamicObject
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> _values;

    public DynamicClass(IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = _values[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

you can build objects form the class like this:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
values.Add("Username", "value which you read from database");
values.Add("Status_name", "value which you read from database");
values.Add("FirstName","value which you read from database" );

var client = new DynamicClass(values);
```

and then you can easily access the fields of this class like:

```
dynamic clientDyn= client ;
var username= clientDyn.Username;
```

Comment: I Could do it, but the problem is that the fields I want to select are created dynamically. I'm doing a dynamic query, so I don't know if in the creation of the class I create all possible values of the field and that will solve the problem.

Comment: @user3224414 I edited the answer, hope it be useful.